# Prevent Threejs Perspective Camera from having a negative Y value?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

How do you prevent a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` from having a negative `position.y`?

I'm using a slightly modified TrackballControl, to control the camera with my mouse, which is preventing the camera from rotating on the z-axis, but would like to keep my camera above the "ground"

Answer (score 1):

Say that you have 2 cameras. One of them is being controlled by `TrackballControls`. The other one is used for rendering. This is how the render loop would look like:

```
controls.update();

camera2.position.copy( camera.position );

if ( camera2.position.y < 0 ) camera2.position.y = 0;

renderer.render( scene, camera2 );
```

Comment: Is this a common pattern for this sort of thing? I'm pretty new to 3d graphics.

Comment: Nope. It's not common. But, unless you try to hack `TrackballControls`, is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: Is this also how you would keep the camera from rolling? I've hacked around in TrackballControls making a custom control, but I feel that's messy. I think I'd rather have 2 cameras, one which responds to my mouse movements, and one that displays to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `THREE.OrbitControls`, which will keep the camera upright without hacking.

If you use `THREE.OrbitControls`, and you want to constrain the zenith angle to keep the camera above ground, you will need a simple hack.

In `OrbitControls.update()`, replace this line:

```
phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );
```

with this one:

```
phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI/2 - EPS, phi ) );
```